# Subtracting polynomial expressions with Linked Lists?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

So I was given this struct that creates polynomials (input by the user):

```
struct Term
{
    double coefficient;
    unsigned exponent;
    Term *next;
};
```

And I'm supposed to write a function that subtracts two polynomials made from this struct. I wrote the following code, and my code is compiling, but I get weird outputs.

```
TermPtr subtract(TermPtr p1, TermPtr p2) {
//can't change the function declaraction, only the contents in the function

    TermPtr newPoly; //declares newPoly

    newPoly = new Term; //creates new node 
    newPoly -> next=p1; // has next in newPoly point to 
    newPoly -> next=p2; // both p1 and p2 (not sure why really (?))

    if (p1 -> exponent == p2 -> exponent){
        newPoly->coeff = ((p1 -> coeff) - (p2 -> coeff));
    } 

    // if the exponents in each p1 and p2 match, perform subtraction
    // on coefficients


    return newPoly; // return the new polynomial
}
```

This is an example of my outputs:

```
Polynomial 1:
2.00 * X^4 + 1.00 * X^2
Polynomial 2:
1.00 * X^4 + 2.00 * X^2

//polynomial 1 - polynomial p2
//negative numbers are valid
Result of subtracting two polynomials:
1.00 * X^0 + 1.00 * X^4 + 2.00 * X^2 //wrong
```

I think the problem lies somewhere in where my newPoly is pointing to both p1 and p2. I'm not sure which node newPoly should be pointing to or if the two nodes are supposed to be pointing to newPoly. I wrote those lines of code because without them, my code wasn't compiling, which makes sense since newPoly can't just be pointing to nothing (or not being pointed to?). And shouldn't some node end with NULL for it to actually be linked list? Not sure where this would go either.

I've been working on this for a few days and I can't really figure it out. Any help or explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your polynewcan't point to two temptr. Actually you've overridden the next of plynew with p2 . And what you've done is for only first value of p1 and p2. You've to use loop to ove through all the elements of p1 and p2.Don't add anything in polynew firstly.  Starting from the first element check if both p1 and p2 have same exponent if yes then subtract it and add it to polynew. If not then find the bigger one and add it to the polynew. Then do the same till both p1 and p2 list exhausted.

Comment: To expand on Abhishek Panjabi's points: your inputs are two lists:
[termA, termB, TermC] and [termX, termY, termZ]. You need to walk both lists doing the operation. The "return" value portion of operation may need to add additional terms (ie you may need to allocate new nodes in newPoly) to get the correct return value. In short, your return value is a third list of [termM, termN, termP]. I used three values in each of my examples but keep in mind it may be N values.